# Print a String n times using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am having trouble with the following excersice.

Write a method starString that accepts an integer parameter n and returns a string of stars (asterisks) 2n long (i.e., 2 to the nth power). For example:

```
Call    Output  Reason
starString(0);  "*"                    2^0 = 1
starString(1);  "**"                    2^1 = 2
starString(2);  "****"                  2^2 = 4
starString(3);  "********"          2^3 = 8
starString(4);  "****************"  2^4 = 16
```

You should throw an IllegalArgumentException if passed a value less than 0.

I have tried this, but I am looking for a way to multiply the String "*", several times. PD: I can't use .repeat

I am stuck on getting the value of 2 to the n power. As i have tried

```
int x = (int)Math.pow(2,(n));
```

but i don't know what to do with that.

```
public static String starString(int n) {
    if(n<0){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No negative values allowed");
    }
    if(n==0){
        return "*";
    }else{

        return starString(0) + starString(n-1);
    }

}
```

```
test #1:starString(0)
return:"*"
result: pass

test #2:starString(1)
return:"**"
result: pass

test #3:starString(2)
expected return:"****"
your return:"***"
result: fail

test #4:starString(3)
expected return:"********"
your return:"****"
result: fail

test #5:starString(4)
expected return:"****************"
your return:"*****"
result: fail

test #6:starString(-1)
exp. exception:IllegalArgumentException
your exception:IllegalArgumentException on line 3: No negative values allowed
result: pass
```

Comment: Does this need to be solved using recursion only?

Comment: Can you use helper function that invokes recursive function with initial parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, although it will blow up for large n.

```
public static String starString(int n) {
    if(n<0){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No negative values allowed");
    }
    if(n==0){
        return "*";
    }else{

        return starString(n-1) + starString(n-1);
    }

}
```

obviously you can get 2^n using

```
public static int twoToN(int n) {
    if(n<0){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No negative values allowed");
    }
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }else{

        return 2* twoToN(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = (int)Math.pow(2, 4);
    System.out.println(count);
    String value = starString(count);

    System.out.println(value);
    System.out.println(value.length());

}


static String starString(int n) {
    String result = "";
    if (n > 0) {
        result =  "*" + starString(n -1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     public static String starString(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No negative values allowed");
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            return "*";
        } else {
            int pow = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
            int pow2 = pow / 2;
            int starsCount = pow - pow2;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            IntStream.iterate(0, operand -> operand + 1)
                    .limit(starsCount)
                    .forEach(value -> stringBuilder.append("*"));

            return stringBuilder.toString() + starString(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

In every recursive step I count how many stars have to be appended `(pow - pow2)`.

Answer (score 0):

An important optimization that can help with expensive function calls such as this is [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization); if you start with a table containing one star for the case of zero and then populate the table as you return output(s) the output does not need to be re-computed for every step. Like,

```
private static Map<Integer, String> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(0, "*");
}

public static String starString(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No negative values allowed");
    } else if (!memo.containsKey(n)) {
        final String pre = starString(n - 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pre.length() * 2);
        sb.append(pre).append(pre);
        memo.put(n, sb.toString());
    }
    return memo.get(n);
}
```

Then you can print each line (and count the stars) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        String s = starString(i);
        System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", s.length(), s);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
1: *
2: **
4: ****
8: ********
16: ****************
32: ********************************
64: ****************************************************************
128: ********************************************************************************************************************************
```